# Any closed form geometric relationships from the data points to the control points of a Bézier curve?

Tags: closed-form, interpolation, bezier-curve

For a quadratic Bézier curve ($b_2(t)$, with control points $p_1, c_2, p_3$), when $t = 0.5$, the interpolant $b_2(t = 0.5)$ is equidistant from $c_2$ and the midpoint $m_2$ of the line from $p_1$ to $p_3$. Thus we can extrapolate from $m_2$ through $c_2$ to $p_2$.

Can we describe similarly about the control points **only using the data points** when the Bézier curve has higher order? For example, for a cubic one ($b_3(t)$), I tried drawing the control point polygons and only found out the distance from $m_{2.5}$, the middle point between $p_1$ and $p_4$, to $b_3(t = 0.5)$, is $3 \times b_3(t = 0.5)$ to $d_{2.5}$, the middle point between $c_2$ and $c_3$. But if we are only given $b_3(t = 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1) = p_1$ to $p_4$, I'm not sure how $b_3(t = 0.5)$ would play a role in finding $c_2$ and $c_3$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a cubic curve $C$ with control points $P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3$.

Let's denote some "data points" by $Q_0 = C(0) = P_0$, $Q_1 = C(\tfrac13)$ and $Q_2 = C(\tfrac23)$, and $Q_3 = C(1) = P_3$,

Then, by calculating $C(\tfrac13)$ and $C(\tfrac23)$, we know that
$$
Q_1 = \frac{1}{27}(8P_0 + 12P_1 +  6P_2 +  P_3)  = 
      \frac{1}{27}(8Q_0 + 12P_1 +  6P_2 +  Q_3)  \\
Q_2 = \frac{1}{27}( P_0 +  6P_1 + 12P_2 + 8P_3)  =
      \frac{1}{27}( Q_0 +  6P_1 + 12P_2 + QP_3)
$$
You can easily solve these equations to get
$$
P_1 = \frac16(-5Q_0 + 18Q_1 - 9Q_2  + 2Q_3) \\
P_2 = \frac16( 2Q_0 -  9Q_1 + 18Q_2 - 5Q_3)
$$
So $P_1$ and $P_2$ are affine combinations of $Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$, but the geometry is not clear to me, just yet.

There's nothing magic about the parameter values $\tfrac13$ and $\tfrac23$. You could certainly do a similar calculation using $\tfrac14$ and $\tfrac34$, and probably other parameter pairs would work, too. I thought $\tfrac13$ and $\tfrac23$ were most likely to give simple geometric relationships, but no success so far.

In fact [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301736/how-do-i-find-a-bezier-curve-that-goes-through-a-series-of-points) gives formulas involving the curve points at $t=\tfrac14$ and $t=\tfrac34$.

The geometric construction of $Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ from $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3$ is clear from de Casteljau's algorithm, but the reverse is not so clear (to me). But, see my other answer for some geometric ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Where/how did you get $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ from $P_i$?

Comment: By inserting $t=\tfrac13$ and $t=\tfrac23$ into the equation of the curve.

Comment: As it says, $Q_1 = C(\tfrac13)$ and $Q_2 = C(\tfrac23)$.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach (from my other answer) is to use the concept of blossoming, which is explained in [these notes](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs164-09-spring/Handouts/handout19.pdf) written by Lyle Ramshaw. Ramshaw clarified and popularized the blossoming idea, though it was originally developed by de Casteljau in the 1960s.

If $F$ is the blossom of the Bézier curve, then, using the notation from my other answer, we have
$$
P_0 = F(0,0,0) \; ; \; P_1 = F(1,0,0) \; ; \; P_2 = F(1,1,0) \; ; \; P_3 = F(1,1,1)
$$
and
$$
Q_0 = F(0,0,0) \; ; \; Q_1 = F(\tfrac13, \tfrac13, \tfrac13) \; ; \; Q_2 = F(\tfrac23, \tfrac23, \tfrac23) \; ; \; Q_3 = F(1,1,1)
$$
The function $F$ is multi-affine (affine in each variable). The de Casteljau algorithm uses the multi-affine property to calculate $Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ from $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3$. But it seems that knowing the value of $F$ at any four "general" places will let you calculate its value at any other place, again using the multi-affine property. So, in particular, you can calculate $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3$ if you know the curve points corresponding to any four parameter values.

Actually, on page 11 of the notes I cited above, we learn that, provided the cubic curve is twisted in space (i.e. not planar), the blossom point $F(u, v,w)$ can be constructed geometrically as the intersection of the curve's osculating planes at the
three points $C(u) =F(u,u,u)$, $C(v) = F(v,v,v)$, and $C(w) = F(w,w,w)$.

Of course, this requires that $u,v,w$ are distinct, so it won't let us calculate  the control points $P_1 = F(0,0,1)$ and $P_2 = F(0,1,1)$ directly. But there's a modified rule that works, as explained on page 12 of the notes: the blossom point $F(u, v,v)$ can be constructed geometrically as the intersection of the curve's osculating plane at the
point $C(u) =F(u,u,u)$, and its tangent line at $C(v) = F(v,v,v)$. So, in particular, $P_1 = F(0,0,1)$ is the intersection of tangent line at $C(0)$ and the osculating plane at $C(1)$. Similarly, $P_2 = F(0,1,1)$ is the intersection of tangent line at $C(1)$ and the osculating plane at $C(0)$.